# Some questions on Hartshorne's Theorem I-3.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

[image]

1 He said "it is surjective by definition of a regular function", but I feel confused: any $f/g\in$$A(Y)_{m_p}$ with $f\in A(Y),g\in {m_p}$, is not regular on $p$,since $g(p)=0$.

2 I know $A(Y)/{m_p}$ is a field, but why is that $k$?

3 For $dim O_p$= height $m_p$, In think it applies Theorem l.8A(b),
then we can get: height $m_p$+ $dim A(Y)_{mp}/m_p$=$dim  A(Y)_{mp}$=$dim O_p$, but here how can I see $dim A(Y)_{mp}/m_p$=0?

Comment: @Hoot, thanks, I think your answer makes sense to me at least, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) When $A$ is a ring and $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal, the notation $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ stands for $S^{-1}A$ where $S$ is the multiplicative set $A - \mathfrak{p}$. See his notational conventions at the start of the book.

(2) Almost by definition, $\mathfrak{m}_P$ is the kernel of the evaluation $A(Y) \to k$ at $P$, which is surjective.

(3) Strictly speaking, you can't apply (1.8A) to $A(Y)_{\mathfrak m_P}$ because the latter probably isn't finitely generated over $k$. The application is really just
\[
\operatorname{height} \mathfrak{m}_P + \dim A(Y)/\mathfrak{m}_P = \dim A(Y).
\]
We said that the second term is $\dim k$, and fields always have dimension $0$.

On the other hand, note that if $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$ is maximal then $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is naturally isomorphic to the residue field of the local ring $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$.